# Wordpress Database - wp_usermeta and the correct number of session_tokens rows

Tags: database, security

I've been doing some security research for lack of a better term in our database re: specific users and how they access the site.

In the `wp_usermeta` table in the WordPress database, I recently noticed a user with multiple `session_tokens` rows. All other users have one `session_tokens` row in the `wp_usermeta` table except for this user. The information in each of the `session_tokens` rows for this user is exactly the same. I recently forced a log out (through the dashboard) for this user for various reasons, and today I noticed this. Is this normal?

To me it seems odd there would be multiple rows for the `session_tokens` value for a user, but maybe it's just related to the force logout method? I had not done this before.

Comment: Are you saying there were multiple rows _after_ or _before_? Each login session generates a row, that could be on different machines or even the same machine if the browser cookies are cleared, or incognito windows are used. What exactly is the concern?

Comment: Maybe I didn't describe it correctly - at least in my database (which should be the standard DB as I didn't change anything), the `wp_usermeta` table includes one row where the `meta_key` == `sessions_tokens`. The `meta_value` for this row contains session info for each user. But for this one user, there are *two* `session_tokens` rows, where every other user only has one. Just curious why this happened and/or if it's normal.

Comment: That sounds like a glitch to me. I'd take a backup, delete one of the rows and then wait and see if it comes back.

Comment: That's kind of what it feels like given the number of users in the database (it's a fairly large number) - no other user has more than one session_tokens row in the wp_usermeta table. I'll get to this a little later and attempt to report back.